# How to add new executable in xcode for a cpp file?

Tags: c++, xcode

How can I add a new Executable in my XCode project?

Hi,

I add a .cpp file in my XCode project. And the xcode project compiles fine afterward.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Starting main " << endl;
}
```

But how can I execute that main in my xcode project?
I assume I need to create a new custom executable. And I have read
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/080-Defining_Executable_Environments/executable_environments.html

What I don't know what to put is the path of the executable. What should I put? I just create a .cpp file with a 'main'.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to create new Target?

Comment: If that solve my problem, yes. But how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Targets and the create a new target. The executable will be created automatically.

You only need to define custom executables explicitly when (a) you have a legacy makefile project or (b) you are developing some kind of plug-in which will run with a third party application.